# Render Views filters as select list in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, nodes, drupal-8

I am moving now to from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

I found in "`Entity reference`" that there is no "`Render Views filters as select list`" check box to enable in content type/filed setting.

the Idea is when I try to filter in view I want to filter based on select list not by text search.

Assume that I have Node "`Staff`" with fields (`Staff name` and Job `title`)
Staff name is text type
Job title is entity reference to another node called (`Job title`).

Now in staff view I want to add exposed filter called "Search by job title" so I can select one of job title and search, I simply can't find "is one of" criteria?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Views module in Drupal 8 doesn't provide this feature, but there is an issue about that: https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699

I was also missing that feature on a project that I upgraded from Drupal 7 to 8, and used the following patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2429699#comment-14009873

The patch worked, but you may want to read the comments after that patch and watch if there's a new patch for Drupal 8.

Answer (score -3):

You can use relationships and add the job title in the `FILTER CRITERIA`